# Practical implementations of constrained conforming Delaunay triangulations

Tags: algorithm, mesh, delaunay

I need to create a mesh of vertices to use for pathfinding, given an existing outline. I think that for my use case a constrained conforming Delaunay triangulation algorithm would be best suited, however i dont know how to implement such algorithm.

What are possible practical(not theoretical) implementations of CCDT? Or at least what should i research into in order to come up with my own implementation?

I am using c#, but any language example would be helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at [Triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html)?

Comment: +1 to Triangle. Can't speak to this problem specifically, but IME implementing computational-geometric and adjacent algorithms, 1) you want to implement as few tests on actual floats as you can and use them over and over (Shewchuk did this with Triangle; if you don't use Triangle you should at least read his writeup), and 2) there are a SHOCKINGLY large number of degenerate cases that get handwaved away in theoretical writeups.

Comment: If your goal is compute some sort of buffer/offset polygon you could try to check boost geometry or polygon libraries, there is also clipper library which is ported to c#

Comment: There is [C# port of triangle](https://github.com/Geri-Borbas/Triangle.NET) out there also.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are searching for an implementation of constrained Delaunay triangulation (CDT) in 2D, with a conforming algorithm.

You definitely do not want to implement a CDT yourself. Having it robust is difficult, and requires to use dedicated exact number types for degenerated cases.

There exists several open-source implementations of CDT in 2D (both with the conforming algorithm). I can cite [Triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Equake/triangle.html), implemented in C, from Jonathan Shewchuk, and [CGAL 2D triangulations](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title26), implemented in generic C++ (with C++ templates), by the CGAL project. For CGAL, the conforming algorithm is in the 2D mesh generator chapter: see [Building Conforming Triangulations](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/index.html#title2). To be honest, I have to say that I am the author of the 2D conforming algorithm in CGAL.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working in C#, the Triangle library that was cited in some of the other answers may be a good solution for you if you can use unmanaged code. I've used it and it is excellent. Although Java is not your language of interest, I've got a Java implementation at https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour which might present an example of an more object-oriented API.  There are also some write-ups on the ideas and applications of the Constrained Conforming Delaunay Triangulation which might help you figure out how to apply the CCDT to your particular problem. You can find these at https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour/wiki/About-the-Constrained-Delaunay-Triangulation and https://github.com/gwlucastrig/Tinfour/wiki/Tutorial-Using-Polygon-Based-Constraints